# A question about annihilators of elements on modules over PID's

Tags: modules, principal-ideal-domains

Given $M$ an abelian group which is an R-module, where $R$ is a P.I.D., then, for $\alpha, \beta \in M$ and if

$Ann(\alpha) = (s),$
$Ann(\beta) = (t)$

Where both $s$ and $t$ are irreducible elements in $R$, is it true that $Ann(\alpha + \beta) = (st)$? It seems true for me, but I just cannot prove (or disprove) it.

Just proved it:

Let $\alpha, \beta$ as previously. If $r \in \(st)$ then $r\alpha + r\beta = 0$ clearly.

Conversely, if $r\alpha + r\beta = 0$ then $r\alpha = -r\beta$ therfore $0 = rs\alpha = -rs\beta$, thus $rs \in Ann(\beta)$ which means $t|rs$, but $(t,s)=1$ (they are distinct irreducibles), thus $t|r$, with the same argument $s|r$ and then $r \in (st)$.

Comment: I'm curious what could be gained by writing $M$ multiplicatively. For $r\in R, m,n\in M$ that means $r(mn)=(rm)(rn)$, and $rmn$ is ambiguous. Do you get something in return that is worth that kind of confusion? Or is there a specific module you have in mind which makes sense to write multiplicatively?

Comment: It is confusing, indeed, I'll change it since it does not interferes the result. It is because this doubt emerged when I was working with the dual of a finite abelian group (the group of characters of this group) over a polynomial ring, so for me it was natural to write in this way (though, actually I have a distinction for both "produtcs").